# How to add Isactive true in fflib for Account share selector class

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I need to retrieve the user or group where `Isactive =true`, I have added as in the code but getting error

> First error: Invalid field 'IsActive' for object 'Group'

```apex
public List<AccountShare> selectByAccountId(Set<Id>accountIds,Set<Id>
accountshareIds,Set<Id> userIds) {
    String Team = 'Team';       
    return(List<AccountShare>)
        Database.query(
            newQueryFactory()
            .selectField('Rowcause')
            .selectField('AccountId')
            .selectField('AccountAccessLevel')
            .selectField('OpportunityAccessLevel')
            .selectField('UserOrGroupId')
            .selectField('UserOrGroup.IsActive')
            .setCondition(' RowCause !=: Team AND UserOrGroup.IsActive =TRUE')
            .toSOQL());
}
```

Comment: Hi! The error message you're receiving is self-explanatory, as there is no `IsActive` field available on the Group object (and since UserOrGroup field is a polymorphic one you should use a field that is available on both objects or modify your query to take that into consideration.)